# gdb refusing to step into Mesa OpenGL APIs

Tags: opengl, gdb, mesa

I have a very similar problem to [How to step into openGL APIs by using gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043483/how-to-step-into-opengl-apis-by-using-gdb). I want to step into the implementation of `glClear` (for example). I have compiled a Mesa library with debug information, and I notice inconsistent behaviour in GDB.

```
(gdb) p glClear
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff74d0ca0 <glClear>
(gdb) b glClear
Breakpoint 3 at 0x7ffff74d0ca0
(gdb) step   # IT HAS STEPPED OVER THE BREAKPOINT!?
358     glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);
```

I check `info shared` for this symbol location,

```
...
0x00007ffff7482f80  0x00007ffff74e24e2  Yes         /home/user/devroot/lib/libGL.so.1
```

GDB is claiming this shared library is missing debug information (the lack of an `(*)`), but it certainly has debug info, as can be verified,

```
> file /home/user/devroot/lib/libGL.so.1
/home/user/devroot/lib/libGL.so.1: symbolic link to libGL.so.1.2.0
> file /home/user/devroot/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0 
/home/user/devroot/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=be24031397474019aa23062146c4d6eef45cb5e0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

I notice this is a "text symbol"

```
> nm /home/user/devroot/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0 | grep -i 'glclear$'
0000000000068ca0 T glClear
00000000000249ea t __indirect_glClear
```

Is this a bug in GDB, a misunderstanding? How can I step into OpenGL API functions?

**Edit:** (extra research thanks to hint from @datenwolf)
I got the idea to step by instructions, which landed me in a function called `shared_dispatch_stub_203` within `libglapi.so.0`.

This did some peculiar segment addressing,

```
│  >0x7ffff7412b60 <shared_dispatch_stub_203>       mov    0x53461(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffff7465fc8     │
│   0x7ffff7412b67 <shared_dispatch_stub_203+7>     mov    %fs:(%rax),%r11                                │
│   0x7ffff7412b6b <shared_dispatch_stub_203+11>    jmp    *0x658(%r11)                                   │
│   0x7ffff7412b72 <shared_dispatch_stub_203+18>    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)                      │
│   0x7ffff7412b7d <shared_dispatch_stub_203+29>    nopl   (%rax)
```

Where the `jmp` instruction landed in `_mesa_Clear`, which was in the memory map of the `/home/user/devroot/lib/dri/iris_dri.so` library. I can step through this implementation now!

I'm not using glvnd, but it seems the jump magic is used anyway. It's curious why `iris_dri.so` is claimed to have no debug information by GDB however, since I am stepping its source code in GDB now.

Comment: OpenGL function dispatch is messy. Most likely your system has GLvnd installed and the `glClear` you're stepping into is not the one of Mesa, but the one of GLvnd, which will go through some low level jump magic to dispatch very quickly into the proper OpenGL implementation. GLvnd is required on systems that require multiple, different OpenGL drivers, like you have with Nvidia hybrid graphics.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am not using glvnd, but your comment gave me some more ideas, which I updated in my question.

Comment: I wonder why would you care stepping into them. Most likely they push a command onto some queue that's read by another thread at a later time -- so you won't be able to 'step into it' anyways.

Comment: I would like to understand what I'm doing, and "most likely" doesn't fill me with confidence. In this case, there's a *lot* more than just pushing stuff to a queue.